# Share NSArray Contents between multiple methods in a single class

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

What am I doing wrong? My code crashes when I try to log the array. Here is my class:

```
@interface ArrayTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    NSArray *array;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed;

@end

@implementation ArrayTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window, array;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Banana", @"Apple", @"Orange", @"Pear", @"Plum", nil];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed {

    NSLog(@"%@", array);

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [array release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common memory management error in Cocoa. The `arrayWithObjects` method of the `NSArray` class returns an autoreleased object. By the time you try to log the array in the `buttonPressed` method, the array has already been released and you get a crash. The fix is easy:

```
array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Banana", @"Plum", nil];
```

Or:

```
array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Banana", @"Plum", nil] retain];
```

I guess the first one is better, the retain on the end of the second example is easy to miss. I would suggest that you read some more on memory management in Cocoa.